# Flutter - custom toggle buttons selection

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a row of toggle buttons (on/off selectors) which is basically a row of containers and each container is a category and is clickable.

**Q:** How to make it so in a way when one category is selected all the others get deselected?

This is the categories widget I've build:

```
Widget header(){
  return Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, left: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 6.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                        onTap: (){},
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                          ),
                          child: Text('All',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                        onTap: (){},                        
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                          ),
                          child: Text('category 1',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                        onTap: (){},                        
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                          ),
                          child: Text('category 2',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                        onTap: (){},                        
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                          ),
                          child: Text('category 3',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                      InkWell(
                        splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                        onTap: (){},                        
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                          ),
                          child: Text('category 4',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 6.0,)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}`
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVEguaQWGAY

Comment: use [ToggleButtons](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ToggleButtons-class.html)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way would be to use `ListView.builder` to build your items and save the selected indexes but you can also modify your existing code to save selected items in a list and check to see if the item is in the list and if it is then add selection format and refresh the page. You can implement that as shown below,

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  List<String> selectedCategory = new List<String>();
  String all = 'All';
  String category1 = 'category 1';
  String category2 = 'category 2';
  String category3 = 'category 3';
  String category4 = 'category 4';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Test'),
            ),
            body: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: header()
            )));
  }

  Widget header(){
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0, left: 0.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 6.0),
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(height: 4.0,),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                          onTap: (){
                            selectedCategory.add(all);
                            selectedCategory.add(category1);
                            selectedCategory.add(category2);
                            selectedCategory.add(category3);
                            selectedCategory.add(category4);
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selectedCategory.contains(all) ? Colors.blueAccent[100] : Colors.grey[500],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                            ),
                            child: Text('All',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                          onTap: (){
                            selectedCategory = new List<String>();
                            selectedCategory.add(category1);
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selectedCategory.contains(category1) ? Colors.blue[100] : Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                            ),
                            child: Text('category 1',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                          onTap: (){
                            selectedCategory = new List<String>();
                            selectedCategory.add(category2);
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selectedCategory.contains(category2) ? Colors.blue[100] : Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                            ),
                            child: Text('category 2',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                          onTap: (){
                            selectedCategory = new List<String>();
                            selectedCategory.add(category3);
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selectedCategory.contains(category3) ? Colors.blue[100] : Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                            ),
                            child: Text('category 3',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 2.0,),
                        InkWell(
                          splashColor: Colors.blue[100],
                          onTap: (){
                            selectedCategory = new List<String>();
                            selectedCategory.add(category4);
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: selectedCategory.contains(category4) ? Colors.blue[100] : Colors.grey[300],
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
                            ),
                            child: Text('category 4',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 6.0,)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Hope this helps.

Comment: this looks good and satisfies my requirements, but is it considered as best practice? I think there's room for improvements and optimization.

Comment: That was just an example to give you an idea on how you can achieve what you want based on your existing code but a best approach would be to save the selection state in database so that it's preserved for later but really depends on your goal.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this piece of code can be optimized, but so far this worked just fine:

```
class Header extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HeaderState createState() => _HeaderState();
}

class _HeaderState extends State<Header> {

  List<bool> isSelected;

  @override
    void initState() {
        isSelected = [true, false, false, false, false];
        super.initState();
    }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      children: <Widget>[
        ToggleButtons(
          borderColor: Colors.transparent,
          fillColor: Colors.transparent,
          borderWidth: null,
          selectedBorderColor: Colors.transparent,
          selectedColor: Colors.transparent,   
          splashColor: Colors.transparent,       
          children: <Widget>[
            !isSelected[0] ?
            Container(            
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 1',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
            )
            :Container(     
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),       
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 1',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
            ),
            !isSelected[1] ?
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 2',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
            )
            :Container(  
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),          
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 2',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
            ),
            !isSelected[2] ?
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 3',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
            )
            :Container(  
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),          
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 3',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
            ),
            !isSelected[3] ?
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 4',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
            )
            :Container(  
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 3.0),          
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 4',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
            ),
            !isSelected[4] ?
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[300],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 5',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[900], fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),),
            )
            :Container(            
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 12.0),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueAccent[100],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(48.0)),
              ),
              child: Text('cat 5',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
            ),
          ],
          onPressed: (int index) {
            setState(() {
              for (int i = 0; i < isSelected.length; i++) {
                isSelected[i] = i == index;
              }
            });
          },
          isSelected: isSelected,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```